# why are new controls showing up in my form AND panel

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, visual-studio, controls

i have a form with a few controls on it, i have a panel with different controls on, That panel is above the form controls.

i have added new controls to the form and when i place the panel back over the form, the new controls are showing through the panel itself, but only the new one controls and not the "old" ones, if i copy and paste a control or add a new one it has the same effect.

i have looked in the designer.cs and the new controls are being added to the form and NOT to the panel itself.

this is weird and iv checked various properties but cannot immediately see the reason for this.

i have made MANY forms before and this is the 1st time this is happening.

one the note of controls, is there a way to change the default value of the labels "AutoSize" property from TRUE to FALSE; i'm using visual studio CE2015

any ideas on what to check? im really stumped by this one.

Comment: I find your textual description of the problem difficult to follow. I've read it three or four times, and I'm still not sure I completely understand the behavior you're seeing. But it *sounds* like this is just a Z order problem. The "new" controls are higher in the Z order than the panel, so they are being displayed on top of the panel.

Comment: but how does the z order get all screwed up? i really dont know what else to add, the panel "hides" the controls on the form, but when i add new controls to the mainForm then it shows through the panel..

Comment: New controls that you add get inserted at the top of the Z order.

Comment: Is this a MDI form ?

Comment: no, just a standard form, though i have not specifically changed it to MDI

Comment: It probably has something to do with "when i place the panel back".  Whatever that might mean.  Troubleshoot Z-order and container ownership problems with View > Other Windows > Document Outline.

Comment: @HansPassant, i love you, problem sorted, moved the control down the list and it worked. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to check the z-order of your controls.

In the picture below you can see a form I created with two buttons and a panel as you were describing. Neither button is one the panel, however *button 3* has a z-order that puts it on top, just as the *panel* is on top of *button 2*

[image: Form with z order buttons]

If you right click on the controls you want to change the z-order of you see *Bring to Front* and *Send to Back*. Choose the appropriate option.

[image: Change z-order]